# Какой аналог стиля Roboto-Medium в Android приложении?

Tags: android, android-studio, шрифты

Возникла необходимость в андроид-приложении поставить на кнопку шрифт **Roboto-Medium**.

Но столкнулся с тем что в `AndroidStudio` из коробки есть только такой набор шрифтов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в результате гугления нашел, что шрифты семейства **Roboto** применяются в **Google**. И я так понял, что в основном для Android они и предназначены. Но, странно что в списке выбора в студии их то и нет!

Попытки нагуглить какой из предложенных студией шрифтов будет аналогом **Roboto-Medium** - как-то пока безуспешны.

Не очень хочется сидеть и штудировать литературу по истории развития типографии и шрифтов в частности, как-то вообще не очень радужная перспектива.

Подскажите, может их нужно как то заливать в студию вручную или какую то либу ставить? Или ссылку на какой-то мануал подскажите, пожалуйста.

---

**UPD:**

Пробую ставить  `android:textStyle="bold"` - получается толще чем такой же шрифт если сравнивать с гугловскими образцами. 
Перепробовал остальные шрифты которые предложила студия - не подошли. Самый близкий к **Roboto-Medium** получился **sans-serif**, но он все же тоньше.

Comment: Roboto - шрифт созданный специально для андроида и он стоит по умолчанию. Medium можно поставить с помощью textAppearance

Comment: @Flippy Попробовал: android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"  Но у меня шрифт просто стал не капслоком а обычным, имею ввиду что первая заглавная капслок, остальные в нижнем регистре.

Comment: Вариант выбрать просто "medium" без обращения к стилям отсутствует.

Comment: Можно скачать конкретный шрифт и закинуть его в папку fonts в студии. Тогда он будет доступен в меню выбора шрифтов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так "Roboto" действительно для андроид и разработан был.

Шрифт ***Roboto-Medium*** это ни что иное как ***sans-serif-medium***.

Попробуйте вручную ввести в xml разметке вашей кнопки:

`android:fontFamyly="sans-serif-medium"`
либо
`app:fontFamyly="sans-serif-medium"`

Должно сработать.

---

**UPD 12.10.2018:**
Данный способ сработает с версии `API21` и выше. (Спасибо @EugeneKrivenja за резонное замечание).
Но, если же Вам, все еще нужна поддержка версий с 15 по 20. В таком случае, все же придется имплементировать нужный шрифт в проект.

Comment: Отлично работает `app:fontFamyly="sans-serif-medium"`. Спасибо! А то уже начал искать шрифт для того чтобы скачать и запихнуть в проект.

Comment: С API16 доступны `regular`, `light` и другие, но не `medium`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to

Comment: У меня "minSdkVersion 15". Когда  вводил - android:fontFamyly="sans-serif-medium", Студия выделила строку желтым и указала что доступно с АПИ 16 и выше. А когда "android:..." изменил  " app:..." перестало выделять желтым. Все вроде как норм. Хотя на АПИ ниже 23 не тестировал пока.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja По поводу того с какой точно версии был введен - не буду спорить, так как этим вопросом специально не задавался и в этой сфере на звание эксперта никогда не претендовал. Достаточно того, что это работает.

Comment: @DroidCrafter, ваш вопрос отмечен автором как принятый, кто-то может поверить вам наслово. Лучше допишите уточнение в ответ.

Comment: @V.March, у студии нет проверок на неймспейс `app`, вот и все :) Проблема как была, так и осталась.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Эх. Придется все же поискать аппарат с АПИ =15.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  Исправил информацию в ответе. Спасибо за замечание, буду впредь более конкретнее указывать иформацию.

Answer (score 4):

`Roboto Medium` это `sans-serif-medium`, доступный начиная с API21.
На более ранних API его нет в системе.

Начиная с `Android Studio 3.0` есть возможность подключать шрифты от различных провайдеров.

Подробнее читайте здесь:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts